# How to see fontFamily name?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, fonts

I am working on Ubuntu with a react native project. I have some special fonts that I must use on my project whose file names are:

- TSTARPRO-Bold.ttf
- TSTARPRO-Medium.ttf
- TSTARPRO-Italic.ttf

I have already linked them with my project in the package.json and with:

```
react-native link
```

In my stylesheet I have tried a lot of possible names, but any one worked. Like:

```
fontFamily: 'TSTARPRO-Medium'
fontFamily: 'TSTAR PRO-Medium'
fontFamily: 'TSTARPRO'
fontFamily: 'TSTARPRO Medium'
fontFamily: 'TSTAR PRO'
```

Anyone knows any way to see the name that the project has established for these fonts?

Thanks

Comment: Are you creating a font face? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face